# Quickbooks API - .NET - QBD - V2 - Does anyone have working example in C# of how to delete or revert errored objects?

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform, ipp-qbd-sync

Does anyone have a working example in C# of how to delete or revert objects that have been labeled as Errored by the sync process?

I am creating a .Net app that uses V2 of the QuickBooks API to push invoices to Intuit.

Most recently, I have apparently pushed an invoice to Intuit that it has determined to be "bad".

When I look for similar questions, I see a number of answers that I need to revert or delete these, but cannot find any example of how to do so.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

PFB .net code snippets.

For querying error objects

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.CustomerQuery qbdCustomerQueryErroredObjects =  new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.CustomerQuery();
qbdCustomerQueryErroredObjects.ErroredObjectsOnly = true;
IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer> qbdCustomers = qbdCustomerQueryErroredObjects.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer>(context) as IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer>;
```

To query sync status of an object

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.SyncStatusRequest syncSt1 = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.SyncStatusRequest();
syncSt1.ErroredObjectsOnly = true;
syncSt1.OfferingIdSpecified = true;
syncSt1.OfferingId = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.offeringId.ipp;
syncSt1.NgIdSet = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.NgIdSet[1];
syncSt1.NgIdSet[0] = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.NgIdSet();
syncSt1.NgIdSet[0].NgId = "949162";
syncSt1.NgIdSet[0].NgObjectType = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.objectName.Customer;

//Optional Params
//syncSt1.StartCreatedTMS = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90);
//syncSt1.StartCreatedTMSSpecified = true;
//syncSt1.EndCreatedTMS = DateTime.Now;
//syncSt1.EndCreatedTMSSpecified = true;
IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.SyncStatusResponse> syncResultCustomers = commonService.GetSyncStatus(syncSt1);
```

To delete error object

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer customerToDelete = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer();
customerToDelete.Id = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.IdType() { idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.idDomainEnum.NG, Value = "949162" };
customerToDelete.SyncToken = "1";
commonService.Delete(customerToDelete);
```

You can do all these using ApiExplorer as well.

You can check by executing a query and setting ErroredObjectsOnly=true.

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0015_Retrieving_Objects#Objects_in_Error_State

If the entity is in error state, you can query for the specific reason using the SyncStatus API:

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncStatus

From there, you will need to delete or revert the object in error state, depending on if a sync has occurred.

Delete (sync has not occurred):

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/Deleting_an_Object

If a successful sync did occur with the entity at least once, but then an Update pushed it into error state, you will need to do a Revert:

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Manas.  I Am unable to find any of the following under the API explorer: Customer Delete, Invoice Delete.  Are you able to provide URLs to these?

Comment: I am successfully using your example to fetch statuses on invoice.  I am repeatedly seeing one that is: "MBL Netter success using QB SDK ext_ack_id".  Can you please tell me what it means, and where a listing of the sync status messages can be found?

Comment: The sync status messages can be found at:https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/syncstatus                        The MBL netter success message means the writeback to desktop file was successful from cloud with an acknowledgement id. It is an internal message.